# How to separate JSON values which contains specific JSON array

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I need to get the fileName value of the dependencies JSON array and put it into separate array(like java list). If it each JSON Array object contains the JSON array called "vulnerabilities" put it into another list or JSON object along with "fileName","cvssScore" and "severity"
This is the JSON Object. It's a pretty big JSON so I uploaded to Drive

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1puZRU4XY5loLBnBqo2NvKajj_dBR7Ol7

I can get a specific values by going straight like following.

```
String jsonFile = "C:\\Users\\Dexter\\IdeaProjects\\autoupgrader\\target\\dependency-check-report.json";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(jsonFile)));

JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(br);
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(tokener);
JSONArray ja = object.getJSONArray("dependencies");
JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jo2 = jo.getJSONObject("evidenceCollected");
JSONArray ja2 = jo2.getJSONArray("versionEvidence");
JSONObject jo3 = ja2.getJSONObject(0);
System.out.println(jo3.getString("value"));
```

Then I tried to get by converting it to arraylist but I can't find a way to figure it out.

```
List <JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<ja.length(); i++){
    list.add(ja.getJSONObject(i));
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the initial list you can either use the loop you already have, or you can use the Java Stream API:

```
List<JSONObject> items = StreamSupport.stream(dependencies.spliterator(), false).map(d -> (JSONObject) d)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With this way you can easily filter all the objects containing a key "vulnerabilities":

```
List<JSONObject> items = StreamSupport.stream(dependencies.spliterator(), false).map(d -> (JSONObject) d)
        .filter(o -> o.has("vulnerabilities"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To generate the second list containing all vulnerable files, with their fileName, cvssScore and severity you can extend the previous example:

```
List<JSONObject> items = StreamSupport.stream(dependencies.spliterator(), false).map(d -> (JSONObject) d)
        .filter(o -> o.has("vulnerabilities"))
        .flatMap(o -> StreamSupport.stream(o.getJSONArray("vulnerabilities").spliterator(), false)
                .map(d -> (JSONObject) d)
                .map(v -> {
                    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
                    j.put("fileName", o.getString("fileName"));
                    j.put("cvssScore", v.getString("cvssScore"));
                    j.put("severity", v.getString("severity"));
                    return j;
                }))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result of this is a list of JSON objects. You can easily adjust the output, or add some more attributes if you want to.